# NLP: lemmatization with lemmaGen c++

Tags: c++, nlp, lemmatization

I am enhancing a chatbot and I wish to find the lemma of the words from the input sentence. The chatbot is written is c++ and I have found a free open source lemmatization tool called LemmaGen. I have download version 2.2 for c++ but it comes with no documentation on how it is referenced or even used.

Has anyone had any experience with LemmaGen for c++ in the past? Any information will be helpful.
Many Thanks

Comment: lemmatization is a challenging task.

Comment: have you successfully used lemmaGen for C++? I'm currently facing the same problem. Can I invite you to answer it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151476/how-to-use-lemmatisation-lemmagen-in-c?noredirect=1#comment61841682_37151476 here?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use c++ version, but I did use C# version. The use of LemmaGen for C# is simple and quite straight forward. First you initialize object of type Lemmatizer with parameter of model file and then you can call it's public method to Lemmatize word represented as string. So all you have to do is tokenize your text and then lemmatize each token one by one. Method returns string which represents lemma of input word.

I guess that use of C++ version is similar.