# How to use lemmatisation (LemmaGen) in C++

Tags: c++, nlp, lemmatization

I'm using LemmaGen (http://lemmatise.ijs.si) for text lemmatisation. I've successfully used it by running the following statement in the command line.

```
 $lemmatize -l $./data/lemmatizer/lem-m-en.bin  input.txt output.txt
```

However, I actually want to use it as a library in my C++ project programatically. Any one knows how to use LemmaGen C++ API? Thanks!

Or anyone can suggest other C++ lemmatisation library that can be used in C++ programmatically?

Please correct me if I'm asking the question wrongly as I'm still quite new to C++.

Comment: Not aware of c++ lemmatizer; give a try to illinois lemmatizer in Java:

Comment: https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/illinois-cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/lemmatizer

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. because my application is in C++, i still prefer for a C++ lemmatizer.

Comment: @HappyCoding any luck?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer has no idea yet...

Comment: @HappyCoding it seems to bloated for my needs, I'll either write a simpler one based on wordnet, or use a simpler stemmer.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, thanks for reply. Stemmer is too much. In my case, I need lemmatise.

Comment: @HappyCoding would you like to cooperate on something based on wordnet? I prefer C to C++ though.

Comment: Possibly duplicated with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569495/nlp-lemmatization-with-lemmagen-c